# simplexml_load_string() giving errors because SOAP response is being passed as &lt; instead of <

Tags: php, web-services, soap

Hey guys I'm trying to create a simple web service whereby the user enters the price in a text box then the database is queried and returns the names of dresses which corresponds to the price but I'm getting an error when I'm trying to pass the soap response in the `simplexml_load_string();`. This is the snapshot of the errors I'm getting:

[image]

Here's my codes for the client.php:

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['search_input']))
{
try
{
    $input = $_POST['search_input'];

    $wsdl = "http://localhost/WebService/UDDI/90210Store.wsdl";

    //$options = array('cache_wsdl'=>WSDL_CACHE_NONE, 'features'=>SOAP_SINGLE_ELEMENT_ARRAYS);

    //$client = new SoapClient($wsdl, $options);

    $debugOption = array('trace'=>true, 'cache_wsdl'=>WSDL_CACHE_NONE, 'features'=>SOAP_SINGLE_ELEMENT_ARRAYS);
    $client = new SoapClient($wsdl, $debugOption);

    $response = $client->viewDressPerPrice($input);

    $soaprequest = "<strong>REQUEST:</strong><br/>" . htmlspecialchars($client->__getLastRequest()) . "<br/>";
    $soapresponse = htmlspecialchars($client->__getLastResponse());

    echo $soapresponse;

    if(isset($response->DressPerPrice))
    {
        $XMLDocument = simplexml_load_string($soapresponse); //this part giving errors  
        $XSLDocument = new DOMDocument();
        $XSLDocument->load("WSEx1.xsl");
        $XSLProcessor = new XSLTProcessor();//PHP5
        $XSLProcessor->importStylesheet($XSLDocument);

       echo $XSLProcessor->transformToXML($XMLDocument);
    }

    else
    {
        echo "This field is not found in database";
    }
}

catch(Exception $e)
{
echo 'Exception: '.$e->getMessage();
}

catch(SOAPFault $exception)
{
echo 'SOAP Exception: '.$exception->getMessage();
}

}

else
{
header("Location: http://localhost/WebService/Client/Category.html");
}

?>
```

var_dump($response); result:

> object(stdClass)#2 (1) { ["DressPerPrice"]=> array(5) { [0]=>
>   object(stdClass)#3 (3) { ["Name"]=> string(7) "Dress 2" ["Price"]=>
>   int(20) ["Image"]=> string(24) "" } [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UovAC.png)=> object(stdClass)#4 (3) {
>   ["Name"]=> string(7) "Dress 9" ["Price"]=> int(20) ["Image"]=>
>   string(6) "3.jpeg" } [2]=> object(stdClass)#5 (3) { ["Name"]=>
>   string(8) "Dress 10" ["Price"]=> int(20) ["Image"]=> string(19)
>   "0905C58A0179_1.jpeg" } [3]=> object(stdClass)#6 (3) { ["Name"]=>
>   string(8) "Dress 11" ["Price"]=> int(20) ["Image"]=> string(19)
>   "0905C58A0179_1.jpeg" } [4]=> object(stdClass)#7 (3) { ["Name"]=>
>   string(8) "Dress 12" ["Price"]=> int(20) ["Image"]=> string(19)
>   "0905C58A0179_1.jpeg" } } } 
>   Dress
>   220<img
>   src="2.jpeg"></img>Dress
>   9203.jpegDress
>   10200905C58A0179_1.jpegDress
>   11200905C58A0179_1.jpegDress
>   12200905C58A0179_1.jpeg

Any way that I can fix this?
Your help will be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I think you might want to pass `$response` to the `simplexml_load_string`, and not the `$soapresponse` which is `htmlspecialchars`ed

Comment: When i pass $response it gives me the error that i'm passing an object instead of a string.

Comment: So what exactly is returned by `$client->viewDressPerPrice($input);`? Can you `var_dump( $response );` and share the result?

Comment: Without having the wsdl I'm kind of guessing already, but could you try not using `htmlspecialchars()` on `$client->__getLastResponse()` ?

Comment: Could you format your result a little better, it's not really that readable as is.

Comment: @mrun You're right that was the mistake but now my xslt is not displaying correctly. I guess i have to create another post for that.